# Sticky sidebar accordion won't scroll propperly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a sticky sidebar (using code of w3schools if it looks familiar), and have added an accordion menu in it.

The aim is that the sidebar is there permanently, but doesn't take up the whole screen until the user scrolls down below the header. If the user opens an accordion menu and the menu needs a scroll bar, there should be an individual scrollbar appear for the sidebar.

However, bizarre things happen occasionally. If I have a page where there is too much content then the scrollbar for the sidebar will only appear once the sidebar is sticky. If the content fits on one screen (so the sticky aspect never comes into play) the scrollbar for the sidebar doesn't appear. Instead it is a main window scrollbar, which stops me scrolling down the sidebar propperly.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
    <button class="accordion">Grade 1</button>
    <div class="panel">             
        <a href="Note-Types.html" style="border-top: solid silver;">Note Types</a>
        <a href="Time-Signatures-Bar-Lines.html" style="border-top: solid silver;">Time Signatures and Bar Lines</a>
        <a href="Beaming-Notes.html" style="border-top: solid silver;">Beaming Notes</a>
        <a href="Note-Names.html" style="border-top: solid silver;">Note Names</a>
        <a href="Rests.html" style="border-top: solid silver;">Rests</a>
        <a href="Accidentals.html" style="border-top: solid silver;">Accidentals</a>
        <a href="Dots-Ties.html" style="border-top: solid silver;">Dots and Ties</a>
        <a href="Semitones-Tones.html" style="border-top: solid silver;">Semitones and Tones</a>
        <a href="Scales.html" style="border-top: solid silver;">Scales</a>
        <a href="Key-Signatures.html" style="border-top: solid silver;">Key Signatures</a>
        <a href="Degrees.html" style="border-top: solid silver;">Degrees</a>
        <a href="Intervals.html" style="border-top: solid silver;">Intervals</a>
        <a href="Triads.html" style="border-top: solid silver;">Triads</a>
        <a href="Foreign Terms.html" style="border-top: solid silver;">Foreign Terms</a>        
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">Grade 2</button>
    <div class="panel">
        Coming Soon
    </div>                  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#sidebar {
    padding-left:5px;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height:100%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;
    font-family: 'Annie Use Your Telescope';
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;

}
.accordion {
    background-color: rgb(213,218,255);
    color:black;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 15px 8px 15px 16px;
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    letter-spacing: inherit;
}

.panel {

        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;

}
.sticky{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.sticky + .content {
    padding-top: 60px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}


window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("sidebar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
}
```

The code is currently being used on a website which is live so you can check that out for ease of use. The only thing not visible is some of the sidebar content and the css as they are in seperate files. Best pages to check out are http://learningmusictheory.co.uk/index.html - click on grade 1 in sidebar and try to scroll down; and http://learningmusictheory.co.uk/Note-Types.html - click on grade 1 in side bar and you have to scroll main window down until the sidebar becomes stick to then scroll through the sidebar links.

Thanks for your time, it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to work, it checks if either of the "panels" from the menu have a larger height value than the #main-content div, and if it is, it ignores the rest of the original part of the function:

```
function myFunction() {
    if ((document.getElementsByClassName("panel")[0].clientHeight || document.getElementsByClassName("panel")[1].clientHeight) > document.getElementById("main-content").clientHeight){
    return;
    } else {
        if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        navbar.classList.add("sticky")    
        } else {
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
       }
    }

 }
```